# XPath Syntax - unknown element value

Tags: xpath

I'm using XPath to extract a table from HTML. I have a unique situation where I only know half of my elements attribute value and am trying to write an xpath expression to find the half I know and ignore the rest.  For example

```
HtmlNodeCollection cols = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='Iknowthis_DontKnowThis']");
```

After looking w3 schools I see that there are wild card operators for selecting unknown nodes but I cant find anything that says how to use them in a situation like this.

Ive tried something like this but cant get anything to work:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td[@class='Iknowthis_.*']");
```

Maybe its not possible?  I'm not sure?

Comment: What `xpath` library are you using in what programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I am using C# with HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's preferred if you edit and update your question with more information (e.g. in response to comments) rather than commenting clarifications, it makes your question easier to understand and index for present and future readers. (May be worth have a read of the [site FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask))

Answer (score 1):

I've been over the w3schools xpath docs several times, I don't think you can use wildcards for substring matching (while testing for equality in predicates).

You could use some of the [<strike>string functions</strike>](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_functions.asp#string) [string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions). E.g.:

```
"//td[starts-with(@class,'Iknowthis_')]"
```

You may need to prefix the `starts-with` function with a namespace, (e.g. `fn:starts-with`), it depends on the implementation.

There is also a `matches` string function which takes patterns.

Comment: Thanks Matt, this information led me to another thread that contained the solution:
//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' Iknowthis_ ')]

Comment: While I'm not really in the w3schools haters camp, you will probably get flack for even referencing them (see http://w3fools.com/). So here's the equivalent w3c doc: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions. And you should never need to prefix the starts-with function with a namespace - it's a basic XPath 1.0 string function.

Comment: @Tao: Really? Gosh, I'd never come across this phenomenon. Darn shame from that point of view that w3schools have the first two hits when searching Google for `xpath`... and that the [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions) docs aren't especially readable.

Comment: Note that `matches` is XPath 2.0 only.

Comment: And the `fn:` prefix isn't necessary in XPath 2.0 and is wrong (would cause an error) in XPath 1.0. The OP seems to have only XPath 1.0 available, and this excludes the use of `matches()`

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use function 'contains()':

```
//td[contains(@class, 'Iknowthis')]
```

also you can use function 'not()' to exclude smth:

```
//td[not(contains(@class, 'Iknowthis'))]
```